# Separate opacity for border in rectangle - QML

Tags: background, qml, border, opacity, rectangles

I want to change the opacity of the border in the rectangle but not change the opacity of the background rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you always start with the documentation and only then, in case of failure, with the help of the community. Moreover, the Qt/QML documentation is quite detailed and clear.

As for your case you have to play with the [border color](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html#border.color-prop), or rather with the alpha component of the [color](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-color.html), for example:

```js
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Border test")

    Flow {
        id: background
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            property int cols: Math.floor(background.width / 50);
            property int rows: Math.floor(background.height / 50);
            model: repeater.cols * repeater.rows
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: 50
                height: width
                color: {
                    var row = Math.floor(index / repeater.cols);
                    var col = Math.floor(index % repeater.cols);
                    return row % 2 ? (col % 2 ? "#EFEFEF" : "#FFFFFF") : (col % 2 ? "#FFFFFF" : "#EFEFEF")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 300
        height: 300
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "orange"
        border.width: 50
        border.color: "#80306090" // the same will work with Qt.rgba(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5)
        radius: 25
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code:

```
   Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: rubberBand
        color: "transparent"
        opacity: 0.5

        visible: rubberBand.visible
        border.width: 3
        border.color: "#8F30FA"
    }

    //! Rubber band to handle selection rect
    Rectangle {
        id: rubberBand

      width: 240
      height: 240
      x: 0
      y: 0
      color: "#8F30FA" 
      opacity: 0.2
}
```